# PHP version differ on localhost and remote server

Tags: php, localhost, version, joomla3.0, remote-server

I develop Joomla Site on php 7.1.1 version and Joomla 3.6.1 version on local host. Now I want to move site on remote server but on remote server php available version upto 7.0 then how to deal with this case.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Upgrade the PHP version on remote, otherwise if it's a shared host, you'd either have to ask them to upgrade or source your own VPS-type setup.

Comment: Joomla 3.6.1 or later should be as happy to run on PHP 7.0 as 7.1. See https://docs.joomla.org/Technical_requirements for the technical requirements. Ideally upgrade to the latest version of Joomla so that all the current security patches are applied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply